# Swift - 'textFields' is inaccessible due to 'fileprivate' protection level

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoapods, textfield

I've added a pod that personalize my alert (PCLBlurEffectAlert)
After editing alert, alertaction, and alert textfield, I have this error and I can't use the textfield. What can I do?

[image]

```
let alert1 = PCLBlurEffectAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("AGGENTRATA", comment: ""),
                                   message: NSLocalizedString("insENTRATA", comment: ""),
                                   effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark),
                                   style: .alert)
    alert1.addTextField( with: { (textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("ENTRATA_LOCAL", comment: "") //impostiamo il segnaposto del field
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = false //se fosse un campo Password mettremmo true
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    } )

    alert1.addAction(PCLBlurEffectAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("ANNULLA_LOCAL", comment: ""), style: .cancel,  handler: { (action) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            self.blurVisual.effect = nil
        })
    }))
    alert1.addAction(PCLBlurEffectAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("AGG", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            self.blurVisual.effect = nil
        })
        let textField = alert1.textFields![0] as UITextField
```

Comment: Try to post code not image.

Comment: ok, I posted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textfields` is a private variable in the `PCLBlurEffectAlertController`. So we can't access the private variable.

> fileprivate var textFields: [UITextField] = []

You can use like this :

```
var textfield1: UITextField?

let alert1 = PCLBlurEffectAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("AGGENTRATA", comment: ""),
                                              message: NSLocalizedString("insENTRATA", comment: ""),
                                              effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark),
                                              style: .alert)
alert1.addTextField( with: { (textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("ENTRATA_LOCAL", comment: "") //impostiamo il segnaposto del field
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = false //se fosse un campo Password mettremmo true
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
        self.textfield1 = textField
} )

alert1.addAction(PCLBlurEffectAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("AGG", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        let textField = (self.textfield1?.text as! NSString).floatValue
}))
```

Comment: I took your advice. I replaced it with textfield1 also below where it gave me the error, after a couple of suggested fixes I run the app and perform its task..have a yellow alert saying 'Forced cast from' String? ' to 'NSString' only unwraps and bridges; did you mean to use '!' with 'as'?' The app is not mistaken, so I do not consider it, right?

Comment: Where you are getting this warning?

Comment: let a = (textField?.text! as! NSString).floatValue <- Here I got it